# Should I define my Lambda functions inside a single Lambda function or each one sepeartely

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-lambda-layers

Since Lambda charges me per invocation, wouldn't it be more cost efficient if I define all functions within a single file?
Or do they charge per function invocations regardless of the .py files?

Comment: The request cost is `$0.20 per 1M requests`, with the fist 1M requests free each month. The run-time of your Lambda functions is likely to result in a more significant charge.

Answer (score 2):

For pricing, you get charged at the millisecond level, so the quicker and tighet each function is the better.

To keep with the idea and design of "Microservices" and follow the "S" in SOLID principles, you usually want a lambda function to do one thing.

The minute you start having lambda functions do two or more things, you're now tying those lambdas and logic together. Ideally a lambda function shouldn't need to know about another lambda function.

You can have one lambda invoke another, but you typically want some sort of eventing orchestration in place to do that for you like Eventbridge or SNS or Step Functions.

So I would avoid putting 3 sets of functionality into one lambda function because now you're vastly limited that functions ability to be reused by other parts of the application potentially.

Answer (score 0):

Lambda charges are based on the number of invocations of your function and the time it takes for your function to run.
Whenever your lambda function is called, it will be charged for the invocation and its duration.

**Case 1 (Single purpose design):**
You want to implement 3 functions,
For example - ADD(),SUBTRACT(),DIVIDE()
you created a lambda function for each function.

Whenever any of your functions are called,you will be charged for that invocation.
If you called ADD()[Lambda function] then SUBTRACT()[Lambda function] then DIVIDE()[Lambda function], you will be charged once for each lambda function means total of 3.

**Case 2 (Monolithic design):**
You want to implement 3 functions, you wrote all three functions into different .py files but into a single Lambda function because AWS Lambda allows only single handler per Lambda function and these functions will be invoked according to the condition.

Whenever you are going to call any of the function, same Lambda function will be invoked everytime.
If you call ADD() function then SUBTRACT() function then DIVIDE() function, you will be charged for same Lambda function call every time means total of 3.

So, whether you write a separate lambda function for each function or single Lambda function for all functions, you will be charged for the number of calls and duration.

> It is better to create separate Lambda functions for each function
> because debugging will be easy in this case.

To know more about AWS Lambda pricing - https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/pricing/